# Connect to SQL Server Management Studio over VPN (Hamachi)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I just got my Hamachi VPN set up. For anyone familiar with Hamachi, I have it set up as a gateway so I'm part of the network when I'm away.  Almost everything seems to be working perfectly.  I can even backup using Windows Home Server if I want.

I cannot connect to my SQL Server from SQL Server Management Studio.  Of course, when I'm at home, everything works perfectly.  I can communicate with the database server just fine remotely (i.e., ping).  I just can't connect with SSMS.  The network configuration is at the default (TCP Enabled).

Does anyone know

- Why I can't connect?
- How I can determine why I can't?

Extra info:

1. Using a Workgroup, not a domain.
2. Using port 1433 to connect
3. Connecting to the default instance

Answer (score 1):

Have you allowed remote connections in Surface Area Configuration -> Services and Connections -> Remote Connections?

I haven't specifically tried recently, but I have enabled TCP & Named pipes. You can also force a protocol if you need to, e.g. in the server name, use NP:myserver in order to force named pipes, or TCP:myserver in order to force TCP.

Try enabling named pipes in the connection setup too - client and server.

Also, hamachi normally uses its own IP range, so you should check that you can actually telnet to port 1433 of your server.